# Oracle Select max where a certain key is matched

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm working with oracle, plSql, i need to query a table and select the max id where a key is matched, now i have this query

```
select t.* from (
select  distinct (TO_CHAR(I.DATE, 'YYMMDD') || I.AUTH_CODE || I.AMOUNT || I.CARD_NUMBER)  as kies, I.SID as ids
from transactions I) t group by kies, ids order by ids desc;
```

It's displaying this data

[image]

If i remove the ID from the query, it displays the distinct keys (in the query i use the alias KIES because keys was in blue, so i thought it might be a reserved word)

[image]

How can i display the max id (last one inserted) for every different key without displaying all the data like in the first image??

greetings.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns or expressions with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: oh, so if i use distinct and select the id, by default every row will be distinct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select thekey, max(sid)
from (select t.*,
             (TO_CHAR(t.DATE, 'YYMMDD') || t.AUTH_CODE || t.AMOUNT || t.CARD_NUMBER) as thekey,
             t.SID 
      from transactions t
     ) t
group by thekey
order by max(ids) desc;
```

Comment: that did the trick mate, i accomplished this with a sp, but i had to create arrays, and it was really convoluted, you did it really simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided data in text format, its difficult to type such long numbers and recreated the data.

However I think you can simply use the MAX analytical function to achieve your results.

```
with data as (
select 1111 keys,1 id from dual
union 
select 2222, 1 from dual
union 
select 1111, 2 from dual
union 
select 2222,3 from dual
union 
select 9999, 1 from dual
union 
select 1111, 5 from dual
)
select distinct keys, max(id) over( partition by (keys)) from data
```

This query returns -

```
KEYS    MAX(ID)OVER(PARTITIONBY(KEYS))
1111    5
9999    1
2222    3
```

Comment: the answer by Gordon Linoff works for my particular problem, thanks anyway man